# Windows 8 installed twice - one installation faulty

Tags: windows-8, boot, ssd

I recently did a clean install of Windows 8 Pro to my Dell 1720 laptop HDD. I then decided to add a Crucial M4 SSD as the OS disc and use the HDD for storage in bay 2. I cloned Win 8 from the HDD to the M4 using the Crucial kit and fitted it in bay 1. It refused to boot, citing a disk error (can't recall precisely). Eventually, after trying everything I could think of, I fitted the original HDD in bay 2 and it booted up immediately, which surprised me as I'd read that it would only boot from bay 1.

I want to move my working OS to the SSD and use the HDD for other stuff. I have found a Win 8  repair disc now so maybe could use that on the SSD, but I don't know how to do that.
Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Knowing the exact error message would help. Otherwise just [run Automatic Repair from the DVD](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/http-wwwbleepingcomputercom-tutorials-automatically-repair-windows-8-with-automatic-repair-/) and see if it helps.